# Practical Solutions to HTML5 Video on WordPress

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-recommendation, html5, video-player

I was directed here from Stack Overflow --

We work with clients who have WordPress sites and one thing we keep struggling with is implementing HTML5 video across all browsers and devices in the WordPress environment. We've tried multiple plugins (JW Player, MediaElement, Sublime Video). It seems like each one has its own bugs, and are difficult to implement video play-lists on (Not to mention having a good UI for the client to manage/add videos themselves).

What is a solid, reliable solution to HTML5 video on WordPress? Something that can support up to 4 file types at once (.mp4, .webm, ogg, flash) and possible have a playlist functionality.

Should I ditch the plugin solution entirely and write the code myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an old project, I ended up writing my own. And working with WordPress library to feed the players (audio and video), so there's no foreign UI and a template builds the player with the proper attachment info.

The audio player was implemented with [JPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/).

> #### The jQuery HTML5 Audio / Video Library
>
> jPlayer is the completely free and open source (GPL/MIT) media library written in JavaScript. A jQuery plugin, jPlayer allows you to rapidly weave cross platform audio and video into your web pages. jPlayer's comprehensive API allows you to create innovative media solutions while support and encouragement is provided by jPlayer's active and growing community.

If my memory serves me well, I think I had to use another library to the video due to some playlist issues.

And that was done with this premium player: [HTML5 Video Player with Playlist](http://codecanyon.net/item/html5-video-player-with-playlist-multiple-skins/1382684). They have a WordPress plugin version, but I needed something very customized, so built my plugin with the Html5 code.

Comment: So you basically used the WordPress media uploader to upload the videos, but ran them through a custom player to display them? Also, we actually bought and used the that plugin on Code Canyon, but it was written in PHP shorthand, and we can't turn on short_open_tag on our server due to the affect on other sites that run on that same server. We couldn't use it :/

Comment: When the client needs a *solid solution*, I go with Vimeo Pro.

Comment: The client needs a html5 player with flash fallback AND it needs to be a non-public (clients want members only section) WITH a playlist added to the player... :/ It seems like I can solve any of these on my own but the combination is frustrating. I'll take a look at Vimeo's API. Maybe I can make something work.

Comment: Yes, Vimeo, a role/membership plugin, and good to go.

Comment: Use a WPMU DEV Membership plugin and it worked.